# Erro ao capturar um dado existente

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho dois serviços AJAX. Em um deles eu busco os dados do usuário em um JSON que uma API me retorna, faço um parse dele e peço que ele insira um certo dado pra mim  numa tag

. O código é esse:

```
if(xhr.status == 200){

    console.log(xhr.responseText);

    let ultimaAula = xhr.responseText;
    ultimaAula = JSON.parse(ultimaAula);

    let ultimaAulaAcessada = "";
    ultimaAulaAcessada += ultimaAula.ultimaAulaAcessada;
    document.querySelector("#ultima-aula").innerHTML = ultimaAulaAcessada;

}
```

Pois bem, ele pega o id da última aula e insere pra mim no #ultima-aula. Até aí tudo bem. Ele insere nesta tag

```
<p id="ultima-aula"></p>
```

Agora eu tenho um outro serviço que precisa recuperar esse dado para executar outra ação pra mim.

Eu faço o AJAX dele e nele informo que no #ultima-aula está o id que ele precisa para executar o serviço, porém ele diz que o campo está vazio e não está, porque eu vejo o id sendo exibido na tela. O que pode ser?

Comment: Você não esta conseguindo pegar os dados que esta em "ultima-aula"?

Comment: Isso, ele exibe pra mim na tela, ou seja, mostra lá na tag <p> o id que o ajax inseriu pelo innerHtml, mas quando vou pegar o dado ele diz que está vazio

Comment: Se por exemplo, eu pego a mesma tag e insiro um id a mão, ele executa o serviço. Mas quando vem do ajax ele não executa

Comment: Isso que você quer? https://jsfiddle.net/a9m18dww/

Comment: Como está o código que pega o conteúdo da id #ultima-aula?

Comment: Resolveu o problema. Vi que fez outra pergunta e ignorou esta.

Comment: Então, na verdade eu resolvi, mas não da forma esperada. Eu coloquei um setTimeout no segundo código com um segundo de delay e funcionou